# Add annotation outside of stratigraphic plot

Tags: r, plot, lattice

How can I add some annotations to a stratigraphic plot?

For example, here's Stratiplot from analogue:

```
library(analogue)
data(V12.122)
Depths <- as.numeric(rownames(V12.122))
names(V12.122)

(plt <- Stratiplot(Depths ~ O.univ + G.ruber + G.tenel + G.pacR,
                   data = V12.122,  
                   type = c("h","l","g"),
                   zones = 400))

plt
```

[image]

I want to add some text in the white space between the blue plots and the zones rectangle on the far right. For example, like this:

[image]

With A = 150, B = 600, C = 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
pacman::p_load(analogue)
data(V12.122)
Depths <- as.numeric(rownames(V12.122))
names(V12.122)

(plt <- Stratiplot(Depths ~ O.univ + G.ruber + G.tenel + G.pacR,
                   data = V12.122,  
                   type = c("h","l","g"),
                   zones = 400))

(plt2 <- Stratiplot(Depths ~ O.univ + G.ruber + G.tenel + G.pacR,
                   data = V12.122,  
                   type = c("h","l","g"),
                   yticks = c(150,600,1000)
                   ))
```

We need to update the y-axis labels like this:

```
plt2$y.scales$labels <-  c("A", "B", "C")
```

And then we can plot it with the two y-axes like so:

```
require(latticeExtra)
doubleYScale(plt,plt2,add.axis=T)
```

[image]

I checked out the source code of this function and figured out that it was a wrapper around `xyplot` then I did a search to find out that `doubleYScale` can be used this way to add a 2nd Y axis to an `xyscale`.

Or to keep the colours uniformly black,

```
doubleYScale(plt,plt2,add.axis=T,use.style = F)
```

Comment: Very neat, thanks! I'm going to add `update(trellis.last.object(),   par.settings = simpleTheme(col = c("black", "black")))` to keep the colours a bit more uniform...